# What's making my rake task source different libraries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake, rvm

When I'm on `master` and I run `rake` from command line Rake executes the following command:

```
$ rake
/Users/meltemi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/models/factories_spec.rb
```

However, if I switch to another branch and run `rake` I get:

```
$ rake
/Users/meltemi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby -I/Users/meltemi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib:/Users/meltemi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@myapp/gems/rspec-support-3.3.0/lib /Users/meltemi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@myapp/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/exe/rspec ./spec/models/factories_spec.rb
```

Why has `-S` in the first example been replaced with `-I/Users/.../lib:/...`?

**RVM** is my Ruby manager...

Comment: Did your `.rvmrc` file or `.ruby-gemset` file change (or be added) in your new branch? The second command looks like it's using the `myapp` gemset, whereas the first is just using the latest rspec version in your Ruby install.

Comment: I don't believe so. There is no project specific `.rvmrc` and `.ruby-gemset` is untracked by the project's `.gitignore`. However, the version of RSpec being used is different between these two branches. The first is using v2.14 while the latter is using 3.3.2 which are both present in the `@myapp` which is used by both examples...which is why I'm curious why one needs to explicitly specify the executable in the gemset while the other one does not?!?

Comment: It's possible that both gems are in the gemset, but 2.14 is the default whereas 3.3.2 needs to be explicitly loaded. This is probably handled by Bundler somehow, but I don't know enough about the actual details of it to make this a proper answer.